# Jersey 1.x to 2.x using CDI

Tags: java, cdi, jersey-2.0, tomcat8, weld

I am working on a web service currently using Jersey 1.17 and CDI (Weld 2.4.1). I'm running on Tomcat8. My `ContextListener` and resource classes are successfully being injected with my service implementations marked with `@Inject`. I'm trying to move to Jersey 2.x, but I've hit a road block.

My only change of note is in my `pom.xml` and `web.xml`.

```
-        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
+        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
-            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
+            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
```

My resource classes are no longer being injected despite the fact that my `ContextListener` is. I'm seeing the following:

```
26-May-2017 12:03:42.596 WARNING [http-nio-8888-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=PlatformService,parent=PlatformResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,379054017)
```

I see the Weld log messages indicating the Weld seems happy, but I'm really at a loss.

```
2017-05-26 12:03:19,870 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.j.w.e.servletWeldServlet {} - WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer 
2017-05-26 12:03:19,894 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.j.w.Version {} - WELD-000900: 2.4.1 (Final) 
2017-05-26 12:03:20,173 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.j.w.Bootstrap {} - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously. 
2017-05-26 12:03:20,503 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.j.w.e.servletTomcat {} - WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
```

Comment: [Check out the docs on CDI support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/cdi.support.html)

Comment: Also the exception you are showing isn't really going from Weld, but rather from HK2 (which is not a complete CDI impl as you might know).

Comment: I'll further point out that hk2 is not a CDI implementation at all lol.  It can be made to work with CDI (as Jersey has done) but it is not CDI itself

Comment: I guess the thing that I'm really confused by is the fact that this is working on 1.17.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in this dependency seems to have resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>
```